# What exactly happens when require() is used on images?

Tags: javascript, require

Codepush etc needs all images to be used with `require` in js. I know that it caches modules and makes them reusable later, but what exactly is `require("/path/image")` doing to images, and why is it something ok to not use it? Just out of curiosity

Comment: caching can only load an image into the cache once, requiring an image a second time, after its file has changed, will still yield the first cached version, unless you manually start cleaning the module cache.